# how to get arabic results in location weather search form " the api support arabic lang "

Tags: php, forms, search, location, arabic

how to get arabic results in location weather search form " the api support arabic lang "

i have the weather results with english lang just
when i input arabic city neme i have no results 
when i replace the location name in link with arabic city name directly i have all inf i need
but when i use the search form i have the results with en lang
the code below .. what can i do to get the results with ar lang !!

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<main class="container text-center"
<h1 class="display-1">حالة الطقس</h1>
<form class="form-inline" method="post">
<div class="form-group mx-auto my-5">
<label class="sr-only" for="location">يرجى ادخال موقعك</label>
<input tupe="text" class="form-control" id="location" placeholder="location" name="location" size="100%">
<button class ="btn btn-primary" type="submit">ابحث الان</button>
</div>
</form>
----
$location = htmlentities($_POST['location']);
$location = str_replace(' ', '+', $location);
$geocode_url =  'https ://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext='.$location.'&app_id=XXX&app_code=XXX';
$location_data = json_decode(file_get_contents($geocode_url));
```

Comment: So if you replace the `searchtext='.$location.'` part manually and call that URL directly in your browser, you get the results you want, but not with this version where you are trying to dynamically insert the value from the form, is that what you’re saying? Then it is probably either due to the fact that you neglected to apply proper URL encoding to the value (which your browser usually applies for you, when its not already in place), or because you have a character encoding issue. Try to apply URL encoding first, and see if that fixes things. `searchtext='.urlencode($location).'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was due to the fact that the dynamically inserted value was not properly URL-encoded, so the fix is to change

```
searchtext='.$location.'
```

to

```
searchtext='.urlencode($location).'
```

---

When you test such a URL by directly inputting it into your browser address bar, the browser usually applies missing encoding where necessary on its own - but other systems don’t necessarily do that, so you need to apply it yourself.

Comment: how can i add the Autocompletion 

http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json
  ?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
  &app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
  &query=Pariser+1+Berl
  &beginHighlight=<b>
  &endHighlight=</b>

Comment: Don’t know what you are asking? Is this supposed to be a similar issue regarding URL encoding - or some completely different topic? If the latter, you should rather ask that in a new question.